# top section of page that doesn't reload wherever you go on that domain

Tags: php, html, header

Is there a way I can have an Identical header on every page in my domain? I don't want the header to have to reload every time someone goes to a new page on that website. Is this possible without frames? And if not having to reload the header while going from page to page isn't possible is it possible to use PHP to prepend that header onto the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can have an Identical header on every page in my domain?

Use a templating system (or an include)

> I don't want the header to have to reload every time someone goes to a new page on that website.

Then you have to use frames. It isn't worth it. It is only a small amount of HTML (which should use HTTP compression to make it even smaller) and any images can be cached.

> And if not having to reload the header while going from page to page isn't possible is it possible to use PHP to prepend that header onto the document?

[include](http://php.net/include)

Comment: I think I'll use includes. Very simple method.

Answer (score 0):

If you really care about your header not being reloaded, despite David's (excellent) answer, you could always populate your body using jQuery and AJAX requests.

Comment: Yes, although possible, David's answer would still be advisable - jQuery and AJAX would add complications (and lots of extra and unnecessary code and work) to allow the back buttons and google indexing (etc.) to still work. Actually, come to think of it, the address bar would still not work with frames. The correct answer is probably just "it's not worth it"